# Is there any efficient ways to locate, open files in Vim?

Tags: vim

I use Nerdtree, it is convenient. But when there is too many files in directories, it is little inconvenient to locate files and open it.

Is there some efficient way to locate, open files in Vim?

Comment: What do you know about your files? Name, partial name, path?...

Comment: How can this question be too localized? Opening files seems like a pretty universal experience... Also, `CTRL-P` is unrelated to this question.  Ahh... I figured it out: this [ctrlp](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

[This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14497166/546861) of mine covers a few of the methods available to you without installing anything. Vim's built-in `**` and tab-completion are your best friends:

```
:e **/foo*/bar<tab>
```

The above mentioned CtrlP is a *great* tool that does a lot more than file navigation. You should try it, as well as the other plugins in my answer.

Also, NERDTree is close to useless because you already have a file explorer in Vim: `:help netrw`.